# Can't use $refs using variable name instead of direct value

Tags: vue.js, refs

I'm trying to call a child component's method from my parent component using $refs. It works if I do it the regular way: `this.$refs.actualNameOfTheChildComponent.someMethod()`

But for my app's needs I have to use a variable name instead of the child component's actual name:

```
const previousAction = `action${i-1}`
this.$refs.previousAction.showConflict()
```

In the second line, Vue doesn't understand that I'm not referring to a child component named `previousAction`, but I'm referring to a child component whose name is the value of the variable `previousAction`.

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing `.something` is just syntactic sugar for `["something"]`. Therefore you can use:

```
const previousAction = `action${i-1}`
this.$refs[previousAction].showConflict()
```

You can read more about the differences between *dot notation* and *bracket notation* [here](https://codeburst.io/javascript-quickie-dot-notation-vs-bracket-notation-333641c0f781).

> There are some important differences between dot and bracket
>   notation:
>
> #### Dot notation:
>
> - Property identifies can only be alphanumeric
>     (and _ and $)
> - Property identifiers cannot start with a number.
> - Property identifiers cannot contain variables.
> - OK — obj.prop_1,
>     obj.prop$
> - Not OK — obj.1prop, obj.prop name
>
> #### Bracket notation:
>
> - Property identifiers have to be a String or a variable that references a String.
> - It is okay to use variables, spaces, and Strings that start
>     with numbers
> - OK — obj["1prop"], obj["prop name"]